# Как передать ForeignKey в POST запрос?

Tags: http, rest, django-rest-framework

Допустим, есть модель `Products`, и есть у нее поле `product_type` - `ForeignKey`, которое содержит ссылку на таблицу `ProductTypes` с типами продуктов, например, `phone`, `laptop`...

Можно ли при `POST` запросе сделать так, чтобы в `body` указывался именно тип - строкой, а не `ProductId`, то есть вот так:

> POST /products

```
{
    ...
    "product_type" = "laptop"
    ...
}
```

У меня пока вариант только перебирать все записи и пытаться найти ту, у которой текстовое представление совпадает с переданным, и заносить уже её `product_id`, но это очевидно супер медленно будет работать, возможно есть какие-то более простые варианты?

Использую фреймворк `Django Rest Framework`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое решение, при создании объекта использовать примерно следующую конструкцию:

```
product_type=ProductTypes.objects.get(name=request.data['product_type'])
```